# TableViewCell内にCollectionViewを置く

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xib, uicollectionview

`xib`で`TableViewCell`を作成し、その`TableViewCell`の内に`CollectionView`を置きました。次にその`CollectionView`の中に`CollectionViewCell`を置こうとするのですが、なぜかセルを置くことができません。`Storyboard`の`UIViewController`に`CollectionView`を置いて`CollectionViewCell`を置くと、ちゃんと置くことができます。また、`Storyboard`では`CollectionView`を置くと`CollectionView`の背景が真っ黒な状態で追加されるのですが、`xib`で`CollectionView`を置くと、初めからセルが網目のように追加された状態で置かれます。ということは`xib`では`CollectionView`の中に`CollectionViewCell`を置くことができないのでしょうか？`CollectionViewCell`が置けないので、`Storyboard`上でセルの`identifier`が設定できず少し困っています。

---追記---

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([CustomCell class]) bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    _collectionView.delegate = self;
    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    [_collectionView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 3;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Collection Viewは、Table Viewを発展させたものと理解してください。Collection Viewのプログラムは、Table Viewのプログラムによく似ています。すなわち、DataSourceとDelegateを駆使して行います。Storyboard上のCollction ViewのCellも、同様にTable ViewのCellと同じ扱い、すなわちPrototype Cells（プロトタイプ）です。Identifierによって、プロトタイプCellと、プログラム上のCellを結びつけます。Table Viewでは、Row（行）数を1以上にしないと、Prototype Cellが現れませんでした。それはCollection Viewでもおなじです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。確かに色々と見ているとTableViewと似ていますね。試しに新しいプロジェクトを作ってシンプルにTableViewのセルの上にCollectionViewを乗せてみようとしているのですが、「'attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell (CustomCell)'」とエラーが出て行き詰まってしまいました。CollectionViewを置いてあるxibはCustomCellクラスと紐付けています。また、PrototypeCellsもTableViewの上に一つ置き、CustomClassをCustomCellにしています。実装に関する部分のコードを追記いたしました。今回の設定でどこがおかしいのでしょうか？

Comment: UITableViewCellのサブクラスをInterfaceBuilder（XIB）で作ると、StoryboardにあるUICollectionViewのPrototypeCellsがありませんね。編集のやりやすさを考えるなら、InterfaceBuilderは使わずに、Storyboardで完結させたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: 了解しました。ひとまずStoryboardだけで作ってみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InterfaceBuilderのXIBファイルを作成してのプログラムを試みてみましたが、煩雑すぎて断念しました。感覚的には、すべてプログラムコードを書いて作成したのち、XIBに置き換え可能な箇所を置き換えるといったもの。Storyboardを使った場合の、どうしてもプログラムコードを書かないとダメな箇所だけコードを書くという感覚とはかなり異なります。

以下は、Storyboardを使って、テーブルビューのセルに、コレクションビューを貼り付けたサンプルプログラムのコードです。

ViewController.h ————

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
// UITableViewとUICollectionViewそれぞれの、DelegateとDataSourceプロトコルを宣言。    

@end
```

ViewController.m ————

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
// テーブルのための配列データ
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *rowArray;
// コレクションのための配列データ
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.rowArray = @[@"Collection", @"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", @"Wednesday", @"Thursday", @"Friday", @"Saturday"];
    self.imageArray = @[[UIImage imageNamed: @"a.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"b.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"c.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"d.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"e.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"f.png"], [UIImage imageNamed: @"g.png"]];
}

#pragma mark- Table View Delegate and DataSource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.rowArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // 1行目のセルのIdentifierは「Collection」、2行目以降は「Week」。
    NSString *cellIdentifier = (indexPath.row == 0) ? @"Collection" : @"Week";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row > 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = self.rowArray[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark- Collection View Delegate and DataSource
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.imageArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // セルのIdentifierは「Image」。
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Image" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 1];
    imageView.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

サンプルの画像：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Storyboardだけでも完結できるのですね。TableViewのセルにCollectionViewを置くやり方が分かり、とても助かりました！ありがとうございました。